# Disk Drive / not ready yet or not available

Tags: boot

I'll tell you the whole story.

I decided to upgrade my natty from alpha to beta after a long time.After the updates has been downloaded, the system crashed during installation. I rebooted the system and during the plymouth screen I greeted with the error message

"Disk Drive / not ready yet or not available"

and options to wait,skip or manually recover

If I choose to skip, it gives the same error,but with /tmp this time.

And if I skip again, it just freezes.

If I choose the option to manually recover, I get a maintenance shell.

Please help.

Comment: Thing I have already tried
Waiting
running fsck
fsck -a, -p,-f
mount -a
running gparted on this drive from a different ubuntu partition

Comment: After a system crash during updgrade your files or filesystem may be corrupted. This can best be fixed with a fresh reinstall.

Comment: I dont want to do it.Thats the whole point.

Comment: I had the same error with a fresh install to 12.04. Worked out the same fix mentioned in Klaus' post.

Comment: **NOTE:** [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/38617/62483) is about the same issue. Hopefully, it can be useful for future users..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after error message. /tmp could not be mounted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted)

Comment: or [Disk drive boot problem: The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or is not present!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454037/disk-drive-boot-problem-the-disk-drive-for-tmp-is-not-ready-yet-or-is-not-pres)

Answer (score 4):

This code works fine on my machine (try it just once and the problem should be fixed):

```
mount -o remount, rw /
```

My Ubuntu is:
Ubuntu 12.04:  3.2.0-49-generic #75-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I ran `fsck` in manual recovery. But I don't remember which atribute label I used - it was check partition and don't repair. I think it `vas -r`. Then console aked me if I wanted to fix this erorr. I pushed "y" for one hundred times and now system boot without problem.