# Disk drive boot problem: The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or is not present!

Tags: mount, tmp

When I started Ubuntu, I got this error: `The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or is not present!` I tried skipping mounting, but it came up like a command prompt.

Please help me.

Comment: did you do an advanced partitioning in ubuntu while installation. this error usually happens when the disk drives are modified from an external source after ubuntu installation. if you have done that, go to /etc/fstab and tell us what it says along with a screenshot of gparted. *alternately try rebooting and be with patience and do not press any key. it should take about 5 minutes but ubuntu should boot into desktop*

Answer (score 7):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo mv /tmp /tmp_old
sudo mkdir /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Reboot, and it should be OK.

Comment: You should enable the sticky bit for `/tmp`, using `chmod -R 1777 /tmp`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Ubuntu - [Ubuntu bug #1091792](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/1091792). It was fixed in mountall-2.48 for Ubuntu 13.04. Unfortunately the latest version in Ubuntu 12.04 is mountall-2.36.4, so it is not fixed (and, presumably, never will be).