# Failed upgrade to 14.04 - /tmp not mounted properly and UUIDS missing from /etc/fstab

Tags: upgrade, mount, fstab, partial-upgrade

I have an old PC with dual boot to Windows Vista (Windows fails to boot though because of an unrepaired avgidshx.sys issue, another story), and on this PC I attempted an upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 using the Software Updater. But the upgrade process froze midway. I had to restart the PC, and an error screen then showed `The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present`. Leaving it from here resulted in an unresponsive black screen, whereas SHIFT + m started a bash shell. From the bash shell:

- `$ ls -ld /tmp` showed these permissions: `drwxrwxrwt`
- /tmp listed in a green colour (because of its executable perms?) and it contained some data.
- I couldn't move or re-create /tmp and:

  ```
  $ rm -rf /tmp
  Cannot remove '...': Read-only file system
  ```
- I couldn't remount /tmp either:

  ```
  $ mount -o remount,rw /tmp
  /tmp not mounted or bad option
  ```
- I couldn't check for matching blkid's because `cat /etc/fstab` contained no UUIDS.
- I tried running `fsck /tmp` but that didn't work either (I don't remember the error message, but it might have recommended trying e2fsck)

My question to the community: is this PC beyond repair, or, how can it be salvaged?

I have a Boot Repair Disc obtained from http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
which, when run, reports the problem is repaired & that I may reboot. But on rebooting I return to the `/tmp is not ready yet` screen.

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/454037/disk-drive-boot-problem/454214#454214

Comment: Hi Simptnon, yes I did try `mv /tmp /tmp_bac` which failed. That's what I meant by saying I couldn't move or re-create /tmp `whoami` showed I was already running as root - didn't use `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could mount /tmp, it looks like fstab is broken, your system is in a partial upgrade state, and the filesystem may have some problems. You could try to fix all of that, but it would be far easier to just do a fresh install on a new partition, then fsck the old partition, and mount it to access any files you care about (ie. /home/hal).