# Home folder does not open and "Continue to wait" message

Tags: 12.04, boot

After I upgraded almost everything in my system (it took a long time and I executed only one command from the terminal, probably sudo upgrade or update), my Ubuntu 12.04 became a mess.

1. It sounds like a Jumbo 747 heavy, where the Windows 7 (on the same laptop, which has a dual-boot) runs smoothly.
2. I am getting the following message during boot:`The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present
   Continue to wait; or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery`
3. Home folder (which I have pinned at the left of the screen) does not open (however the terminal for example does so). In particular it's like it gets opened, because when I try to click something in my Desktop, nothing happens. It's like the home folder has eventually opened, but is not displayed at all!

I am begging for help, since my Ubuntu are actually screaming for help. I was wondering if there is functionality in Ubuntu similar to the one Windows have, that makes the system goes back to 1/5/2015 (for example).

There is this question, but I do not think that it fully adresses my problem: [How do I avoid the "S to Skip" message on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot)

---

If there is no hope for my Ubuntu, then that would be an answer too, so that can I install something else in place of Ubuntu.

---

Edit: Oh God, I can't stand the noise! I will have a chance with re-installing Ubuntu 12.04 or installing a newer version of Ubuntu, how to do that? I find too many different results in Google.

By the way here is what top gives:

```
top - 17:08:13 up  1:27,  2 users,  load average: 1.78, 2.30, 2.39
Tasks: 188 total,   4 running, 184 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 49.5%us,  4.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 45.9%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4028448k total,  2571896k used,  1456552k free,   197796k buffers
Swap:  4083708k total,        0k used,  4083708k free,  1287460k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
 2725 samaras   20   0 1438m 691m  54m R   49 17.6  32:48.67 firefox            
 3461 samaras   20   0  676m 104m  23m R   48  2.6  32:43.48 plugin-containe    
 1823 samaras   20   0  248m  60m  28m S    8  1.5   1:50.59 compiz             
 1319 root      20   0 91892  29m  15m S    5  0.7   2:58.66 Xorg               
 1561 samaras   20   0  4504 2128  632 S    2  0.1   1:23.43 dbus-daemon        
 1842 samaras    9 -11  161m 5476 3924 S    2  0.1   1:24.97 pulseaudio         
 9282 samaras   20   0 16944 7476 3724 R    2  0.2   0:00.05 ubuntuone-syncd    
 6313 samaras   20   0 81424  14m  10m S    1  0.4   0:00.46 gnome-terminal     
 1895 samaras   20   0 67292 9984 7324 S    1  0.2   0:22.98 bamfdaemon         
 2020 samaras   20   0 45000 4584 3576 S    1  0.1   0:11.25 zeitgeist-daemo    
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:04.64 ksoftirqd/3        
  199 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:20.45 kworker/2:1        
 1075 messageb  20   0  3976 1752  840 S    0  0.0   0:15.74 dbus-daemon        
 1135 root      20   0 11080 3556 2676 S    0  0.1   0:00.87 cupsd              
 1169 root      20   0 32504 6072 5000 S    0  0.2   0:05.11 NetworkManager     
 1316 root      20   0 25212 3628 2800 S    0  0.1   0:04.21 polkitd            
 1674 samaras   20   0  234m  16m  11m S    0  0.4   0:21.06 gnome-settings-
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disk drive boot problem: The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or is not present!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454037/disk-drive-boot-problem-the-disk-drive-for-tmp-is-not-ready-yet-or-is-not-pres)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did check the graphics card, since I was told that the high temprature (which caused the fan to work so rapidly, thus making the noise) may came from outdated drivers of the graphics card. However, the drivers were up to date.

As a result, I did a format (and actually upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04). I recorded the steps of the procedure [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/linux-and-cgal/).

Do *NOT* forget to store your *ALL* data, or you [might end up like me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250215/reverse-engineering-on-my-thesis-pdf).