# i am getting the message "serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /"

Tags: boot

I have installed ubuntu from a 'power iso' application on my windows 7 laptop.
I recently updated my ubuntu version from 13.10 to 14.04...after all the downloading was done i was finally asked to restart the computer and on restarting it i got this message "serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /"..press i to ignore,s to skip ,m for manual recovery.

I just pressed 'i' and then i got the message "the disk drivers for /tmp are not ready yet or are not present" press s to skip and m for manual recovery.

I am not getting what to do.please help me in this regard.i am a new user of ubuntu so kindly cooperate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disk drive boot problem: The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or is not present!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454037/disk-drive-boot-problem-the-disk-drive-for-tmp-is-not-ready-yet-or-is-not-pres)

Comment: @Neelam Jogalekar Please close the question if this solved your problem. Otherwise comment.

Comment: I ain't finding any option to close my question.Yea it is solved but i don't know about closing a question here.

Comment: @NeelamJogalekar Below the upvote and downvote button on my answer is a tick. Click that. Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I am not a Linux expert and I would appreciate if someone more knowledgeable could weigh in and confirm this is a safe temporary solution.
Also, here is the [source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/247265) -- all credit goes to the guys that figured this out.

You could try this
There is one more thing that seems to work. Apparently you can manually edit your GRUB file like this:

> gksudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Now find the line similar to this (search for the highlighted part):

> linux    /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=[bunch-of-numbers] loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk **ro rootflags=sync**  quiet splash

Change the ro to rw (as in - instead of mounting as read-only, mount for read-write), save and reboot.

This file is actually auto-generated, but this solution has been working for me for the past few days without any issues (I am also dual-booting with Windows 8 -- no problems there either).

And one more link that could be of interest -- someone who seems to be experiencing this issue filed an official bug report. There is no response yet, but the bug has been "confirmed" and perhaps there will be some useful information posted here soon.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218439&p=13002075#post13002075) for this above quote.
**Google is a powerful tool please use it to its max potential.**

Comment: Yea it did work indeed.At first when i tried it manually by typing the command mentioned above,it didn't work giving me the error "gksudo package is not installed",but then i just tried booting it once again and wen i was asked to choose between different ubuntu options,i chose the 'e=edit commands' and therein i found the 'ro' flag being set.Resetting it to 'rw' and rebooting the system solved my problem.There is absolutely no loss of data throughout the process.

Comment: Great man! @NeelamJogalekar please close the question by accepting as a  answer! thanks.